# How to print out lines starting with keyword and connected with backslash with sed or awk

Tags: awk, sed

For example, I'd like to print out the line starting with `set_2` and connected with `\` like this. I'd like to know whether it's possible do to it with sed, awk or any other text process command lines.

**`< Before >`**

```
set_1 abc def  
set_2 a b c d\  
      e f g h\  
      i j k l\  
      m n o p  
set_3 ghi jek  
set_2 aaa bbb\  
      ccc ddd\  
      eee fff  
set_4 1 2 3 4
```

**`< After text process >`**

```
set_2 a b c d\  
      e f g h\  
      i j k l\  
      m n o p  
set_2 aaa bbb\  
      ccc ddd\  
      eee fff
```

Comment: Kindly do add your efforts in form of code in your question which is highly encouraged on SO, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
awk -v st="set_2" '/^set/ {set=$1} /\\$/ && set==st { prnt=1 } prnt==1 { print } !/\\$/ { prnt=0 }' file
```

Explanation:

```
awk -v st="set_2" '                                # Pass the set to track as a variable st
/^set/ {
        set=$1                                     # When the line begins with "set", track the set in the variable set
       } 
/\\$/ && set==st {                 
        prnt=1                                     # When we are in the required set block and the line ends with "/", set a print marker (prnt) to 1                                
       } 
prnt==1 { 
        print                                       # When the print marker is 1, print the line                                    
       } 
!/\\$/ { 
        prnt=0                                       # If the line doesn't end with "/". set the print marker to 0
        }' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Would you try the `sed` solution:

```
sed -nE '
/^set_2/ {                      ;# if the line starts with "set_2" execute the block
:a                              ;# define a label "a"
/\\[[:space:]]*$/! {p; bb}      ;# if the line does not end with "\", print the pattern space and exit the block
N                               ;# append the next line to the pattern space
ba                              ;# go to label "a"
}                               ;# end of the block
:b                              ;# define a label "b"
' file
```

Please note the character class `[[:space:]]*` is inserted just because the OP's posted example contains whitespaces after the slash.

**[Alternative]**

If `perl` is your option, following will also work:

```
perl -ne 'print if /^set_2/..!/\\\s*$/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

This simple `awk` command should do the job:

```sh
awk '!/^[[:blank:]]/ {p = ($1 == "set_2")} p' file

set_2 a b c d\
      e f g h\
      i j k l\
      m n o p
set_2 aaa bbb\
      ccc ddd\
      eee fff
```

Answer (score 0):

And with this  `awk` :

```
awk -F'[[:blank:]]*' '$1 == "set_2" ||  $NF ~ /\$/ {print $0;f=1} f && $1 == ""' file
set_2 a b c d\
      e f g h\
      i j k l\
      m n o p
set_2 aaa bbb\
      ccc ddd\
      eee fff
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;/set_2/{:b;n;/set_/ba;bb};d' file
```

If a line contains `set_2` print it and go on printing until another line containing `set_` then repeat the first test.

Otherwise delete the line.

Comment: Hi Potong, This sed command works great. Thanks a lot~~